# How can I call the Twilio CLI from a SQL Server job step?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, twilio

I have the Twilio CLI installed on my system and I changed my script execution policy to allow it to run. I'm trying to call twilio api:core:messages:create from within a database job powershell step running as me. The command works flawlessly from a powershell window but in the SQL Server job I'm getting:

'The term 'twilio' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

To further clarify as per Dale: I have created a SQL Server Agent Job using the the SQL Server Agent and it has one step as Type Powershell with this code:

```
twilio api:core:messages:create --from "+1XXXXXXXXXX" --to "+1XXXXXXXXXXXX" --body "Twilio Test"
```

The statement works fine when run in Powershell directly, but gives the above error when the job is triggered.

Thanks!

Comment: This is it: twilio api:core:messages:create --from "+1XXXXXXXXXX" --to "+1XXXXXXXXXX" --body "Twilio Test" with the from and destination numbers and the message body. It hits powershell but then produces the above error.

Comment: It sounds like the SQL Server job sees a different `PATH` environment variable than your interactive sessions. (a) Either add the dir. in which `twilio` resides to the _machine-level_ `PATH` variable or (b), less preferably, use the _full path_ of the `twilio` executable in the job (if the path includes spaces, `"..."`-quote it and prepend `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-))

Comment: +1 for using Powershell and not those awful `sp_OA` procedures. I think you need `Install-Module -Name twilio-powershell-module` maybe add `-AllUsers`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server agent job uses SQLPS.exe, instead of actual powershell installed in the machine.

You need to call the Powershell using command prompt, as specified in the below image. [Reference article](https://www.sqlhammer.com/running-powershell-in-a-sql-agent-job/)

[image: Calling powershell through command prompt]

Comment: If I do this.. 

    cd "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"
 powershell.exe "twilio api:core:messages:create --from '+1XXXXXXXXXX' --to '+1XXXXXXXXXX' --body 'Twilio Test' "

It does not error but it does not work either. I never receive the text.